# Sending variable data in iframe website and submit it

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Is it possible to send data to the iframe website form and submit the form? Like I want to track shipment number and this is the code

```
<?php
$tracking = 'LE783579177';
?>

<iframe src="http://leopardscourier.com/pk/tracking/" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
```

I want to open the tracking form in an iframe and pass the tracking no and submit it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `postMessage()` to handle such a case - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage